# What is the purpose of the "comparison" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two questions tagged [comparison](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison): One question is about the comparative, for which [comparative-degree](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-degree) is already used, and the other one is about the differences between "more than," and "more than what."

Considering there are already [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference), and [comparative-degree](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-degree), are there cases where [comparison](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison) would be a better tag?

Comment: I'd just as soon see **comparative-degree** go away and keep **comparison**, which is applicable to constructions as well as just adjectives and adverbs: *as...as*,*just...as*,*Xer than*, and so forth.

Comment: Would not [tag:comparison] be understood as the tag to use every time a question compare two words/phrases?

Comment: Of course: *Anything which can be misunderstood will be*. But that's a meta-tag use and should be quashed anyway; the question should be retagged.

Comment: I don't follow: Which one would be a meta tag?

Comment: Use to tag a question comparing two words/phrases. That tells you the *form* or *motive* of the question, nothing about its topic or content.

Comment: Meta tags would be tags like [tag:beginner], [tag:homework], or [tag:non-native-speaker] which don't give any information about the question, but who asks it. [tag:comparison] is bad because (generally speaking) there are many questions that are asking for a comparison; even in my question about using _never_ with the past tense I am making a comparison. (I was asking which tag you were calling _meta tag_, not what _meta tag_ means.)

Comment: Quite so. Tagging your question as **negation** or **tense-distinction** or something of that sort tells us what the question is about. Tagging it **comparison** tells us only the shape of the question, which is quite as useless as who asks it or why. That would be a meta-tag.

Comment: From the original announcement of [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/): **The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question.** They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.).

Comment: If we were to choose between [tag:comparative-degree] and [tag:comparison] I’d prefer the former, to avoid ambiguity (and therefore risk of misuse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, we can't actually *delete* tags - all we can do is remove any links to an unwanted tag, and wait for the system to remove it as "unused".

I suggest we re-tag the existing questions linked to *comparison*, and hope it goes away. If not, we can try to make it a synonym of *comparative-degree*. But from what I recall, your options re voting on synonyms are severely restricted by the need to have upvotes in the tag(s) you're trying to change. So it might need a mod to deal with the matter.

My position, obviously, is that *comparison* is at best only useful as a synonym of *comparative-degree*, and I personally would like to see it disappear completely. We should use tags like *metaphor, figurative, simile* for "comparisons" that don't fall within *comparative-degree*.

Comment: How then would you tag discussion of constructions like *as __ as __* or *more __ than __* or *in comparison to __*?

Comment: @StoneyB: Wot? *As warm as toast? More Catholic than the Pope?* Why would they not be fine filed under *metaphor, simile?*

Comment: *As much as you want*. *More trouble than it's worth*

Comment: @StoneyB: I can't see there could ever be enough non-trivial things to ask about in such constructions, to be honest. The general principle is it's better to have too many tags than not enough, but do you want to wade through a few thousand old questions to see if any could usefully be tagged? Of course, you might as well include the couple of examples I gave, if they happen to have been asked. Unless you define the "comparisons" tag as excluding figurative usages. I don't know - use it if you want, but it seems pointless to me.

Comment: Me, I'm personally indifferent. The only use I've ever found for tags was to screen out single-word-requests.

Comment: @StoneyB: Hmm. Well, if you don't care anyway, what's the point in nitpicking over my justifications for binning it?

Comment: Economy. One tag embracing those matters and **comparative-degree** and **superlative-degree**.